# Only getting back 4 ID's from my SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreach

In my query I am going through 6 tables to get information from all 6 those tables. The query does work, but I am only getting back the first 4 ID's and the information that is linked to those ID's. Can somebody see what is wrong with my query?

PS: I am looping my query through a foreach so all the information will show up in a nice table.

```sql
SELECT v.klantNummer,
       v.contactnaam,
       v.telefoon,
       v.adres,
       v.postcode,
       mk.naam,
       sm.CSnummer,
       ol.onderhoudsDatum
FROM `vestiging` AS v,
     systeem AS s,
     systeemContract AS sc,
     onderhoudsLog AS ol,
     systeemMeldkamer AS sm,
     meldkamers AS mk
WHERE sm.id = s.id
  AND mk.id = s.id
  AND v.id = s.vestigingID
  AND s.id = sc.systeemID
  AND sc.id = ol.systeemContractID
```

This is my foreach:

```
foreach($DB->SELECT->onderhoudsGegevens() as $row) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $row['klantNummer'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['contactnaam'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['telefoon'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['adres'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['postcode'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['naam'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['CSnummer'] ?></td>
    <td><?= datetimeToDate($row['onderhoudsDatum']) ?></td>
  </tr>
   <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As there is no limitation in the query, you could have a look at the database directly through phpMyAdmin or the MySQL console to see whether there should be more results after all

Comment: There could only be 4 rows In all the tables?

Comment: It might be more understandable if you used proper joins on the tables. As written, if one of the tables only has 4 matching rows, your results will be limited by that table.

Comment: There is not enough information for us to really answer your question, all we can do is guess. What you could to is remove some tables and joins from the query so you're left with the basics, `vestiging` seems to be your main table. Remember if any of those extra tables don't have data for a row of `vestiging` that row will not show up.

Comment: Maybe he needs some of those sub tables to be OUTER JOINs instead, so it doesnt force his results down... but yeah, we are just guessing. Too little informaiton to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query re-written using the more conventional form using joins. If one or more of your 
tables do not have rows meeting the conditions, you can change their respective joins to LEFT JOIN or OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
    v.klantNummer, 
    v.contactnaam, 
    v.telefoon, 
    v.adres, 
    v.postcode, 
    mk.naam, 
    sm.CSnummer, 
    ol.onderhoudsDatum 
FROM `vestiging` AS v
JOIN systeem AS s
    ON v.id = s.vestigingID
JOIN systeemContract AS sc
    ON s.id = sc.systeemID
JOIN onderhoudsLog AS ol
    ON sc.id = ol.systeemContractID
JOIN systeemMeldkamer AS sm
    ON sm.id = s.id
JOIN meldkamers AS mk
    ON mk.id = s.id
```

For example, if the table `meldlamers` is the table limiting your results, you could try:

```
SELECT 
    v.klantNummer, 
    v.contactnaam, 
    v.telefoon, 
    v.adres, 
    v.postcode, 
    mk.naam, 
    sm.CSnummer, 
    ol.onderhoudsDatum 
FROM `vestiging` AS v
JOIN systeem AS s
    ON v.id = s.vestigingID
JOIN systeemContract AS sc
    ON s.id = sc.systeemID
JOIN onderhoudsLog AS ol
    ON sc.id = ol.systeemContractID
JOIN systeemMeldkamer AS sm
    ON sm.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN meldkamers AS mk
    ON mk.id = s.id
```

Try the above query to see if you get more rows. If not, add LEFT to each of the others (one at a time) until you see more rows.

Comment: Thanks! this worked! Had to place "LEFT" to the rows but it worked :), thanks man!